# How do i evaluate this?

Tags: calculus, limits

**Problem**: Evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{2x^2+3}{2x^2+5})^{8x^2+3}$.

**My attempt**:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{2x^2+3}{2x^2+5})^{8x^2+3}$

$=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{2x^2+5-2}{2x^2+5})^{8x^2+3}$

$=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(\frac{2x^2+5}{2x^2+5}-\frac{2}{2x^2+5})^{8x^2+3}$

$=\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(1-\frac{2}{2x^2+5})^{8x^2+3}$

**My problem**: I am unable to figure out how to proceed further. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{2x^2+5}\right)^{8x^2+3} & = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{2x^2+5}\right)^{\left(\frac{2x^2+5}{-2}\right)(8x^2+3)\left(\frac{-2}{2x^2+5}\right)}\\
& = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{2x^2+5}\right)^{\left(\frac{2x^2+5}{-2}\right)\left(\frac{-16x^2-6}{2x^2+5}\right)}
\end{align*}
Observe that 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(1-\frac{2}{2x^2+5}\right)^{\left(\frac{2x^2+5}{-2}\right)}=e \qquad \text{ and } \qquad \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\frac{-16x^2-6}{2x^2+5}\right)=-8.$$
Therefore the above limit is $e^{-8}$.

**Additional way pertaining to your syllabus:**
Let
$$y = \left(\frac{2x^2+3}{2x^2+5}\right)^{8x^2+3}.$$
Then 
\begin{align*}
\ln y & = \color{red}{-}(8x^2+3) \ln\left(\frac{2x^2+\color{red}{5}}{2x^2+\color{red}{3}}\right) \\
& = \color{red}{-}(8x^2+3) \ln\left(1+\frac{2}{2x^2+\color{red}{3}}\right)\\
& = \color{red}{-}(8x^2+3) \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{2x^2+3}\right)}{\frac{2}{2x^2+3}} \frac{2}{2x^2+3} \\
& = \color{red}{-}\left[\frac{16x^2+6}{2x^2+3}\right] \,\, \frac{\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{2x^2+3}\right)}{\frac{2}{2x^2+3}}
\end{align*}
Now take the limits using your standard limits.

Comment: Do you know any other approach that does not use $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(1+n)^\frac{1}{n}=e$?

Comment: @MrAP Another approach could be to take logarithms first and then evaluate the limits using something like L'Hospitals rule.

Comment: No. Without using L'Hospital's rule. I am asking for another approach because neither  $\lim_{\rightarrow \infty}(1+n)^\frac{1}{n}=e$ nor L'Hospital's rule is in our syllabus and hence they are not allowed.

Comment: @MrAP As you can see the answer involves $e$ (exponential function) so any method that can lead to the evaluation has to involve some concept of logarithm or exponential functions and unless one knows some Taylor series, usage of either of those tools or something similar is almost unavoidable.

Comment: I am not saying we don't have any  $e$ related standard limits in our syllabus. We have the following ($e$ related) standard limits in our syllabus: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\log_e a$ and $\frac{\log_e(1+x)}{x}=1$. Most probably the second one has to be used in this problem.

Comment: @MrAP As I stated previously, you can take logarithm and then instead of using the L'Hospital rule, use the last limit you have listed above. The same algebraic manipulation that I have done in my solution needs to be done there as well. However while learning mathematics , always ask yourself why these results are true?

Comment: @MrAP I have added some steps to show how you can use your limits to get to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}(1-\frac{2}{2x^2+5})^{8x^2+3}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2+5/2}\right)^{(x^2+5/2)\frac{8x^2+3}{x^2+5/2}}=e^{-8}$$